# How can you save an audio file to external storage?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a function to save the audio but don't know how to make it work. Would be nice if anybody would help me out?

```
    private void saveAudio(int sound) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    if (checkPermissionwrite()) { // check or ask permission
        File myDir = new File(root, "/KangleiPdDrums/Sounds");
        if (!myDir.exists()) {
            myDir.mkdirs();
        }
        String fname = "Sound1.mp3";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            file.createNewFile(); // if file already exists will do nothing
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
          
            out.write(sound);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            file.setReadable(true, false);
            String pathed = file.getPath();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved at " + pathed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: `myDir.mkdirs();` If it returns false then display a toast and return. Dont continue.

Comment: Put a Toast() in that catch block.

Comment: `file.delete();`  If it returns false then display a toast and return. Dont continue.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-external-storage-with-examples) could help you out?

Comment: Thanks for answering but this didn't help me out. I can save the audio but it says it is a wrong format when I try to play it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain this

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

In the root variable, he is getting the root reference of the private external storage.

```
if (checkPermissionwrite()) { }// check or ask permission
```

Here even this function is not available in your code but this function will use to take the write permission for the user

```
File myDir = new File(root, "/KangleiPdDrums/Sounds");
        if (!myDir.exists()) {
            myDir.mkdirs();
        }
```

Here he is creating a directory or folder at the root folder of your external storage and then he is checking if this directory already exists or not if not then create the directory.

```
String fname = "Sound1.mp3";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
```

Here he storage the file name in the name folder and create the file and after that, he checked if the file already exists then delete this file.

```
 try {
            file.createNewFile(); // if file already exists will do nothing
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
          
            out.write(sound);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            file.setReadable(true, false);
            String pathed = file.getPath();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved at " + pathed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Here this code is used to write the file/audio at the directory that he created at the start and I think it's simple

Let me provide a link for the Indian and Pakistani users that understand Hindi or Urdu they can understand it through video as well

https://youtu.be/SZPF9KuPIV8